# $\neg (\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}\forall i\geq 0: P)=\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}\exists i\geq 0: \neg P$?

Tags: logic

Let P be some statement. Is my negation correct?

$\neg (\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}\forall i\geq 0: P)=\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}\exists i\geq 0: \neg P$?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is correct.

Comment: It is essentially right. The use of "$=$" is non-standard, the two sentences are logically equivalent but not equal.

Comment: Another elementar question. If we have $A\Leftrightarrow B$ and want to show that $\neg A$ gives a contradiction, then it is enough to show that $\neg B$ gives a contradiction?

Comment: I think yes since: Assume $\neg A$. Then this implies $\neg B$ (since if we had $B$ this would imply $A$). So if we can show that $\neg B$ gives a contradiction, this will show that $\neg A$ gives a contradiction (hence $A$ is true).